# Typescript : How to write promised function/s inside function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write some that let me call promised function or more inside function.

What I'm doing now is something like this

```
myFunction(){
   this.function1().then(data1=>{
      this.function2().then(data2=>{
         //do something
      })
   });
}
function1(){
   return new Promise (response=>{
      //do something
      response(data1);
   })
}
function2(){
   return new Promise (response=>{
      //do something
      response(data2);
   })
}
```

Is there any simple way to run function1() and function2() inside myFunction() ?

EDIT:

I need some how to write 1 function instead of 3 function like this

```
myFunction(){
   //something here to return data1 and continue
      //same thing here to return data2 and continue
          //do something 
}
```

Comment: Change `myFunction` into an `async` function so that you can simply do `await this.function1(); await this.function2();`

Comment: myFunction() is wrok fine but how to let simplify my code instead of 3 function to 1 function

Comment: You can then just `await` on any asychronous operations done in `function1` and `function2` and use it directly in your `myFunction`, without the need to put them in separate functions. Not sure how that will do with readability tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use only one function, without using async, you could do it like this:

```
myFunction(){
   (new Promise (response=>{
      //do something
      response(data1);
   }))
   .then(data1=>{
      (new Promise (response=>{
      //do something
      response(data2);
   }))
   .then(data2=>{
         //do something
      })
   });
}
```

Not sure why you would you want this. It only makes things worse and doesn't simplify anything at all. The `async` way is much batter. But here you go.

Comment: your code need some edits but it worked for me and the 1st reason why i'm doing this ? because its so hard to write and modify codes when there are so many functions.

Comment: I agree, that this is one problem of Object Oriented Programming. But in bigger programs it's nice to split the functionality into multiple functions. It'll probably get more obvious, the more experience you have. For now, it's good to experiment with things to really understand what does and what doesn't work. So have fun experimenting :)

Answer (score 2):

Just like Terry said in his comment, change the `myFunction` into an `async` function like this:

```
async myFunction(){
   await this.function1();
   await this.function2();
}

function1(){
   return new Promise (response=>{
      //do something
      response(data1);
   })
}

function2(){
   return new Promise (response=>{
      //do something
      response(data2);
   })
}
```